# How to nest a Git project at a different root?

Tags: git

I have a project for which I'm using Git. I'm relatively new to Git, but not source control. My project includes a 3rd-party Git repo. That's works fine. (I'm using SourceTree, with "Add Remote"). No problem there.

The problem is that the root if the 3rd-party repo should be two levels down in my project.

```
My Project Root
|
-- My Subfolder
    |
    -- Some Other Repo's Root
```

Make sense? Is this possible?

Comment: Ensure the .git file of the 'Other Repo' is inside the corresponding folder

Comment: Wait, **that's it**? I'll have to try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git [submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) and [subtree](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging) shall work fine for you (Both allow to embed a third party repository within a subfolder). Basically with submodule you include a reference to the third party repository; on the other hand, with subtree you embed the third party repository history within your repo (you may squash the history if you wish).

Comment: Thank you. I think one of these is the right thing for me. Unfortunately, after a few days of reading, I've decided to postpone this activity. To do what I want, I'd have to use a mount point in the "other project" that's one level down, and ignore files for things like grunt, lint, etc.